# Carving data from log file

Tags: bash, shell, logging, extract, multiple-columns

I have a log file containing the data below:

```
 time=1460196536.247325 latency=3:6:7:9:16:(8)ms latency95=11ms latency99=13ms requests=517 option1=0 option2=0 errors=0 throughput=480rps ql=1 rr=0.00% cr=0.00% accRequests=101468 accOption1=0 accOption2=0 accLatency=2:6:7:8:3998:(31)ms accLatency95=11ms accLatency99=649ms accOpenQueuing=1664 accErrors=278
```

I am trying to write  bashscript where I try to carve these values for each line in the log file and write it to a second file:

- time (converted to local time GMT+2)
- latency99
- requests
- errors

Desired output in second file:

```
 time    latency99   requests    errors

 12:08:56   13         517          0
```

Is the easiest way to use regex for this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a Bash solution for version 4 and above, using an associative array:

```
#!/bin/bash
# Assoc array to hold data.
declare -A data
# Log file ( the input file ).
logfile=$1
# Output file.
output_file=$2

# Print column names for required values.
printf '%-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n' time latency99 requests errors > "$output_file"
# Iterate over each line in $logfile
while read -ra arr; do
    # Insert keys and values into 'data' array.
    for i in "${arr[@]}"; do
        data["${i%=*}"]="${i#*=}"
    done
    # Convert time to GMT+2
    gmt2_time=$(TZ=GMT+2 date -d "@${data[time]}" '+%T')
    # Print results to stdout.
    printf '%-20s %-10s %-10s %-10s\n' "$gmt2_time" "${data[latency99]%ms}" "${data[requests]}" "${data[errors]}" >> "$output_file"
done < "$logfile"
```

As you can see, the script accepts two arguments. The first one is the file name of the logfile, and the second is the output file to which parsed data will be inserted line by line for each row in the logfile.

Please notice that I used `GMT+2` as the value to the `TZ` variable.
Use the **exact area** as the value instead. Like, for example, `TZ="Europe/Berlin"`.
You might want to use the tool `tzselect` to know the correct string value of your area.

In order to test it, I created the following logfile, containing 3 different rows of input:

```
time=1260196536.242325 latency=3:6:7:9:16:(8)ms latency95=11ms latency99=10ms requests=100 option1=0 option2=0 errors=1 throughput=480rps ql=1 rr=0.00% cr=0.00% accRequests=101468 accOption1=0 accOption2=0 accLatency=2:6:7:8:3998:(31)ms accLatency95=11ms accLatency99=649ms accOpenQueuing=1664 accErrors=278
time=1460246536.244325 latency=3:6:7:9:16:(8)ms latency95=11ms latency99=20ms requests=200 option1=0 option2=0 errors=2 throughput=480rps ql=1 rr=0.00% cr=0.00% accRequests=101468 accOption1=0 accOption2=0 accLatency=2:6:7:8:3998:(31)ms accLatency95=11ms accLatency99=649ms accOpenQueuing=1664 accErrors=278
time=1260236536.147325 latency=3:6:7:9:16:(8)ms latency95=11ms latency99=30ms requests=300 option1=0 option2=0 errors=3 throughput=480rps ql=1 rr=0.00% cr=0.00% accRequests=101468 accOption1=0 accOption2=0 accLatency=2:6:7:8:3998:(31)ms accLatency95=11ms accLatency99=649ms accOpenQueuing=1664 accErrors=278
```

Let's run the test ( script name is ***sof*** ):

```
$ ./sof logfile parsed_logfile
$ cat parsed_logfile
time                 latency99  requests   errors    
12:35:36             10         100        1         
22:02:16             20         200        2         
23:42:16             30         300        3
```

## EDIT:

According to OP request as can be seen in the comments, and as discussed further in chat, I edited the script to include the following features:

- Remove `ms` suffix from `latency99`'s value.
- Read input from a logfile, line by line, parse and output results to a 
  selected file.
- Include column names only in the first row of output.
- Convert the time value to GMT+2.

Comment: For some reason I get this: (Bash version 4.2.25) `./test.sh
column: line too long
time  latency99  requests  errors`

Comment: I see.  It's the limit of input line length, in bytes, defined by `column`. I edited my answer to use `printf` only.

Comment: How do I remove the 'ms' after 13?  I need to define a log file which it reads line by line from and then writes the output to another file?

Comment: What is the contents of the log file? Is it the same as `input` which is defined in the Bash script?

Comment: Yes, the input file contains the same as input, but there are many thousands rows.

Comment: I see. So would you like to create a separate file for each row that appears in the log file?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/108699/discussion-between-rany-albeg-wein-and-user3580316).

Comment: That worked great, however I dont need the title (time latency99  requests errors) for each column for every row. It works fine to be only in the first row. EDIT: The time has also to be converted to local time GMT+2.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a awk script for you. Say the logfile is `mc.log` and the script is saved as `mc.awk`, you would run it like this: `awk -f mc.awk mc.log` with GNU awk.

**mc.awk**:

```
    BEGIN{
        OFS="\t"
        # some "" to align header and values in output
        print "time", "", "latency99", "requests", "errors"
    }

    function getVal( str) {
        # strip leading "key=" and trailing "ms" from str
        gsub(/^.*=/, "", str)
        gsub(/ms$/, "", str)
        return str
    }

    function fmtTime( timeStamp ){
        val=getVal( timeStamp )
        return strftime( "%H:%M:%S", val)
    }

    {
        # some "" to align header and values in output
        print fmtTime($1), getVal($4), "", getVal($5), "", getVal($8)
    }
```

Comment: I get `awk: mc.awk: line 24: function strftime never defined`

Comment: @user3580316  I am using: `awk --version` : GNU Awk 4.0.1. What awk are you using? If you just `return val` instead, you will get the unformatted timestamp.

Comment: @user3580316 What operating system and awk version do you use, maybe you can GNU awk is installed as gawk and you can run the following command: `gawk -f mc.awk mc.log` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an `awk` version (not GNU). Converting the date would require a call to an external program:

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f

BEGIN {
    FS="([[:alpha:]]+)?[[:blank:]]*[[:alnum:]]+="
    OFS="\t"
    print "time", "latency99", "requests", "errors"
}
{
    print $2, $5, $6, $9 
}
```